# Aure AD Authentication using Policy in API Management Service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an API APP deployed in Azure & I put on Azure Active Directory Authentication. I need that API APP should be accessible outside.(The people who are not using Azure)
I have added that API APP into Api Management Service to use policy & authorize API.
Is any way to do that? Can I use Client Id & client secret to authenticate API APP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use send-request (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#SendRequest) policy as a part of request processing to call into AAD with client id and secret and obtain authentication token to attach to ongoing request. Works best with implicit oauth flow since it requires only single HTTP call.

Comment: I got the answer. I am making mistake while granting permission to backend AD application. so always it says You don't have permission to view this page. I removed the extra stuff & Now it's working.